# What is the keybind to select the ranger's pet?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

I'm playing Pillars of Eternity as a Ranger and I find it very annoying that I can't select my pet through the keyboard. I have to click in its icon every time.

Is there a way to keybind the ranger's pet selection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no obvious way to do it.  However, I have (in Patch 2.0.1) done:

1. Select Pet
2. hit Ctrl-0

Now the pet is always "0" if I hit that key.

Comment: Good one. I binded it as Ctrl+7. So it is like the 7th party member.

Answer (score 0):

Make your pet a "group" and bind it that way.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Could you clarify your answer, possibly with screenshots?